# Insert figure and text in first page of each chapter

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, memoir

I designed the first page of each chapter using the following code.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTER HEADINGS
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[red] (current page.north east) rectangle ([xshift=-7cm]current page.south east);
    \fill[red] ([yshift=-7.525cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-7cm,yshift=-7.325cm]current page.north east);
    \fill[white] ([xshift=-7cm,yshift=-7.525cm]current page.north east) rectangle ([yshift=-7.325cm]current page.north east);
    \node[white, scale=10] (label) at ([xshift=-3.5cm,yshift=-3.7125cm]current page.north east) {\thechapter};
    \node[red,scale=1.85, anchor=west, baseline=label.base] (title) at ([xshift=0.75cm,yshift=-5cm]current page.north west) {#1};

    \node at ([xshift=-3.6cm, yshift=-10cm]current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[white, align=justify, text width=5cm, anchor=north] at ([xshift=-3.6cm, yshift=-12cm]current page.north east) {\lipsum{1}};   
\end{tikzpicture}
    \newpage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to have a picture of a mathematician and a short text about it in **each chapter** like below figure.

[image: ChapterStyle]

How can this be done?

Comment: You already have a picture and a short text so what's the problem?

Comment: I take it you want to add text (with a smaller column width) on the same page?  Flowfram could do it, although you would need to know the page numbers in the preamble, and you would need to manually break any paragraph split across different column widths.

Comment: Paracol would also work, but you would need to manually begin and end it to align with the page bottom.

Comment: @Ignasi & @John Kormylo: My file consists of several chapters, and in each of these chapters I want to write about the life of a scientist, for example, the first chapter about Fourier, the second chapter about Lagrange, and so on. Now I'm looking for a command like
`\chapter{chapter 1} \chaptertext{Fourier's life} \chapterfigure{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}`
I'm going to do this automatically.